# Why isn't JSON being unmarshalled into my Java class?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot and RestTemplate to GET data from an in-house service.  The JSON I'm getting back as the response isn't being unmarshalled into my object and I'm unable to figure out why.  (I'm consuming other similar REST APIs and those are working, so I've done this before.)

The code for making the request is standard stuff:

```
public ChecklistResponse getCurrentStatus(String studentId) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = createRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = this.createHeaders();
    String url = this.createItemStatusUrl(studentId);
    ResponseEntity<ChecklistResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), ChecklistResponse.class);
    ChecklistResponse checklistResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
    return checklistResponse;
}
```

The entire Object tree is large, so I can't really show it here.  ChecklistResponse is simple enough, though:

```
public class ChecklistResponse {

    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private String responseType;
    private Response response;

    public ChecklistResponse() {
    }

    ... getters/setters, equals, hashCode, toString ...
}
```

The start of the JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "httpStatus": {
        "code": "200",
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "responseType": "namespaceURI=\"http://bmeta.xxx.com/student/studentChecklistV0.xsd\" element=\"studentChecklist\"",
    "response": {
        "studentChecklist": {
            "identifier": {
```

I set up interceptors to verify that I'm getting a response back.  I ran it with the interceptors disabled, too, so that I know it's not consuming the response (though I'm using the interceptors successfully elsewhere and the object are properly unmarshalling.)

My question is, how can I debug this problem?  I've tried enabling Jackson debugging, but that yields nothing.  I've set breakpoints throughout the ChecklistResponse class, but it doesn't hit any of those.

Comment: FWIW, I'd recommend looking into Lombok to simplify your model classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the model object `ChecklistResponse` correctly represents the map for the JSON object returned by the API you are testing with.

Comment: I finally did get it working, in part by discovering that the map was wrong.  That said, RESTTemplate doesn't parse the JSON properly.  I had to retrieve the entire JSON object as a string, and use GSON to parse it.  <shrug>

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have forgot to add public parameterless constructor, add one like this:

```
 public ChecklistResponse(){}
```

you should add these constructors to all classes in the object tree.

Another thing to look at is if the issue is a result of the values in the JSON object, ex, unescaped quotation etc .. try to make a unit test with a mocked object with trivial values but none empty/null ones and see if that test can pass or not, case sensitive issues sometimes cause this to fail as well, set break points in the getters/setters, these should be called in the process, make sure they are public as well as the classes themselves, final thing I can think of is the circular reference, make sure you don't have that as well in your object as this will cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But it has one, as do all of the other classes in the object tree.  (I originally generated the objects using Swagger.  I also went through and ensured all arrays are instantiated.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the REST service producing the JSON.  I could capture it and perhaps write my own service to return it.  But I still wouldn't know how to figure out where the unmarshalling is failing.  (When I've had mistakes in the JSON when working on other APIs, it would fail with clear errors.  It's not doing that here.  It's simply not populating the objects.  Frustrating.)

Comment: Circular reference is a possibility.  I'll dig in.  But wouldn't it fail with a stack overflow or other error were that the case?

Comment: you don't have to have control over the service to make a unit test, your unit test can mock the service and return the string which you already have from the real one. it is strange that you don't have an sort of error to be honest, my answer are the first issues which I would check at least.

Comment: Turns out the problem is that the API documentation provided an incorrect map of the JSON response.  I used Swagger to create my model from that map.  For whatever reason, it was broken in a manner that didn't generate any errors.  Sigh.  (If you want to post something about that in another answer, I'll accept it.)